# How to make express download link with GridFsBucket?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, gridfs

As the title says, how do you make a direct download link with a file from mongoDB(GridFsBucket) using express?

The file should be downloadable from memory, as i dont want to save it temporarily on the server.

I have this method:

```
async function downloadFileFromDB(fileId) {
  var gridfsbucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(mongoose.connection.db, {
    chunkSizeBytes: 1024,
    bucketName: 'filesBucket'
  });
  try {
    const stream = gridfsbucket.openDownloadStream(fileId)
    const fileBuffer = Buffer.from(stream)
    return fileBuffer
  } catch (err) {
    stream.on('error', () => {
      console.log("Some error occurred in download:" + error);
    })
    console.log(err);
  } 
}
```

And this route:

```
router.get('/download-file', async (req,res) => {
    const fileId = req.query.fileId
    const ObjectFileId = new ObjectId(fileId)
    const fileBuffer = await fileFacade.downloadFileFromDB(ObjectFileId)
    res.download(fileBuffer)
})
```

But res.download wants a path and not a buffer. Aswell im not sure i can make a buffer directly from the openDownloadStream method.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to write the data to your `res` object. I accomplished this like:

```js
const readStream = gridfs.openDownloadStreamByName(filename);
readStream.on("data", (chunk) => {
  res.write(chunk);
});
readStream.on("end", () => {
  res.status(200).end();
  mongoClient.close();
});
readStream.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log(err);
  res.status(500).send(err);
});
```

So, you may just have to do:

```js
res.write(fileBuffer).end();
//// Instead of doing:
// res.download(fileBuffer);
```